# "Client invalid path, not found in rest table" does anyone know what this Sabre's error means

Tags: rest, web-services, request, sabre

I want to use this API service:

> https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record

and the server responds with this json:

```
{
    "status": "NotProcessed",
    "type": "Application",
    "errorCode": "ERR.2SG.CLIENT.INVALID_REQUEST",
    "timeStamp": "2017-09-12T13:21:29.522-05:00",
    "message": "Client invalid path, not found in rest table"
}
```

Comment: Put the code you are using to do the request. How is your request (payload and headers)? Are you doing a post?

Comment: Yes, it is a POST in postman, here is the request
  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3210750ba5e8f4a73c51e61456f73292

Comment: what endpoint are you hitting?

Comment: https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v1/passenger/records?mode=create

Comment: The problem is indeed with the endpoint. It should be

v2.0.0/passenger/records?mode=create 

You're gonna get a bunch more errors after fixing that.

Comment: thanks bruno for your help, for now I do not have enough reputation to give you a +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the endpoint is not right. After fixing that you'd get many different errors, for example you are referencing a Profile ID ABCDEF that doesn't exist.

I've modified that request so you'd get a successful response.

> v2.0.0/passenger/records?mode=create

```
{
  "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "targetCity": "XXXX",
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
      "AgencyInfo": {
        "Ticketing": {
          "TicketType": "7TAW/"
        }
      },
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "ContactNumbers": {
          "ContactNumber": [
            {
              "Phone": "817-555-1212",
              "PhoneUseType": "H"
            }
          ]
        },
        "PersonName": [
          {
            "GivenName": "TEST",
            "Surname": "TEST"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AirBook": {
      "OriginDestinationInformation": {
        "FlightSegment": [
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-07-20T14:20",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2018-07-20T12:57",
            "FlightNumber": "2404",
            "NumberInParty": "1",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "Y",
            "Status": "NN",
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "LAX"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "AA",
              "FlightNumber": "2404"
            },
            "MarriageGrp": "O",
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "DFW"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AirPrice": {
      "PriceRequestInformation": {
        "OptionalQualifiers": {
          "PricingQualifiers": {
            "PassengerType": [
              {
                "Code": "ADT",
                "Quantity": "1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MiscSegment": {
      "DepartureDateTime": "2018-10-29",
      "NumberInParty": 1,
      "Status": "NN",
      "Type": "OTH",
      "OriginLocation": {
        "LocationCode": "LAS"
      },
      "Text": "TEST",
      "VendorPrefs": {
        "Airline": {
          "Code": "AA"
        }
      }
    },
    "SpecialReqDetails": {
      "AddRemark": {
        "RemarkInfo": {
          "FOP_Remark": {
            "Type": "CHECK",
            "CC_Info": {
              "Suppress": true,
              "PaymentCard": {
                "AirlineCode": "YY",
                "CardSecurityCode": "1234",
                "Code": "VI",
                "ExpireDate": "2012-12",
                "ExtendedPayment": "12",
                "ManualApprovalCode": "123456",
                "Number": "4123412341234123",
                "SuppressApprovalCode": true
              }
            }
          },
          "Remark": [
            {
              "Type": "Historical",
              "Text": "TEST HISTORICAL REMARK"
            },
            {
              "Type": "Invoice",
              "Text": "TEST INVOICE REMARK"
            },
            {
              "Type": "Itinerary",
              "Text": "TEST ITINERARY REMARK"
            },
            {
              "Type": "Hidden",
              "Text": "TEST HIDDEN REMARK"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "AirSeat": {
        "Seats": {
          "Seat": [
            {
              "NameNumber": "1.1",
              "Preference": "AN",
              "SegmentNumber": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "SpecialService": {
        "SpecialServiceInfo": {
          "Service": [
            {
              "SSR_Code": "OSI",
              "PersonName": {
                "NameNumber": "1.1"
              },
              "Text": "TEST",
              "VendorPrefs": {
                "Airline": {
                  "Code": "UA"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
      "RedisplayReservation": true,
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "SWS TEST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```